# What features to consider when buying a bouldering slipper?

Tags: rock-climbing, shoes, bouldering

I've been using the same Evolv shoes for bouldering that I bought for top-roping. It seems like they're worn enough to start considering a new pair of shoes. Since I'm doing bouldering almost exclusively now, I'm thinking about getting shoes designed specifically for that activity. What should I look for and what should I avoid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, the main differences between bouldering and top roping (unless you are an expert) is that you are likely to find yourself trying more extreme positions when bouldering.

Huge generalisation, I know, but when top roping you usually look to conserve energy, assess the pitch, and make vertical gains.

As a boulderer, you will be crabbing, moving up and down, trying extreme holds and moves that you may not risk up a wall.

So look for rock boots that have rubber extending further around the heel and up over the toe. Scuff resistance is a plus, as is a strong fastening system.